# Mapping CHAR oracle type to Boolean in Gorm

Tags: oracle10g, grails-orm, grails-2.3

I've a Char field in the oracle database. The possible values are "S" and "N"

How can I map the values to a boolean field defined in a Grails Domain Object? The "S" value is true, and the "N" value is false.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Grails 2.5.3

For The "Y" value is true, and the "N" value is false.

```
static mapping = {
    boolField column: 'BOOLEAN_FLAG'
    boolField type: 'yes_no'
}
```

For The 1 value is true, and the 0 value is false.

```
static mapping = {
    boolField column: 'BOOLEAN_FLAG'
    boolField type: 'org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use a 'beforeInsert' to handle the conversion.

```
def beforeInsert() {
    boolField = (boolField=='S')?true:false
}
```